# Tomcat 7: BeanInitializazionException with Spring MVC and external property file

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7, properties-file

I have a web application bulit in Spring MVC that has an external property file.
The external file is defined in application-config.xml as follows:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <!-- file di properties  -->
                <value>file:/myfolder/myfilename.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:environment.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

The file is in /myfolder and is under my C:\ folder, but I need to deploy it (in production environment) on a Linux machine in which the property file path is /myfolder.
This web application runs well in Netbeans IDE (8.2) with local Tomcat 7 instance.
I am trying to run it in Eclipse with same local Tomcat 7 instance but I obtain the following exception:

```
ERROR ContextLoader:319 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: \myfolder\myfilename.properties (Impossible to find the path specified)
```

I've tried to change the server configuration in Eclipse, but nothing happens. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If it is in `c:` then specify it as such... `file:C:/myfolder/myfilename.properties`.

Comment: I've edited the question. The app needs to run in Linux machine (in which the path is as written in application-config file)

Comment: The path isn't what you think it is. If it was it would be loaded. Is the path really `/myfolder` or is it more like /usr/<your-user>/myfolder` is `/myfolder` **really** in the root of your file system?

Comment: in the Linux machine, yes it is. In windows, it is under C:\


the fact is that on Netbeans I can run the application on Tomcat, not in Eclipse

Comment: What is, according to you, to root of your file system on Linux? Does your application have permission to read/see that directory/file?

Comment: the root is / and yes, application has permission to read data inside /myfolder. app works correctly on production server (Linux) indeed, but it's not in my local (Windows) machine, running it via Eclipse (I am using 2021-06 version)

Comment: I suspect that NetBeans handles things differently and adding some variables that Eclipse doesn't (I would say that Eclipse is right and NetBeans is wrong). Are you running both Eclipse and NetBeans from the `C:` drive?

Comment: yes, both run on the same path